# When should I purchase Savings I bond up to the limit annually if money allows?

Tags: united-states, bonds

When is a wise choice to purchase Savings I bond up to the limit annually if money allows for higher interest rate and diversification purposes? When is it not a wise choice? Thank you.

Comment: Investment advice is off topic

Comment: You might be able to rescue this question by asking what the advantages and disadvantages if these bonds are compared with other investment vehicles; that has some factual answers. But I think that's probably already been addressed by other Questions here.